# Camera not working after android 5.0.2 update

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop, commonsware-cwac

I was working on an android app that is using the camera ([CWAC](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera)) and it worked ok before updating to android 5.0.2, after the update if I take a picture the camera.takePicture is called in CameraView:

```
postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            camera.takePicture(xact, new PictureTransactionCallback(xact),
                                    new PictureTransactionCallback(xact));
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            android.util.Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                                    "Exception taking a picture", e);
                            // TODO get this out to library clients
                        }
                    }
                }, xact.host.getDeviceProfile().getPictureDelay());
```

This is the PictureTransactionCallback:

```
private class PictureTransactionCallback implements
            Camera.PictureCallback {
        PictureTransaction xact=null;

        PictureTransactionCallback(PictureTransaction xact) {
            this.xact=xact;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            camera.setParameters(previewParams);

            if (data != null) {
                new ImageCleanupTask(getContext(), data, cameraId, xact).start();
            }

            if (!xact.useSingleShotMode()) {
                startPreview();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that if I run the app on android 5.0.2 onPictureTaken from the PictureTransactionCallback is never triggered (I ran the app with debug) on the same phone but with android 4.4.2 onPictureTaken is triggered and simpleCameraHost.saveImage is called. I can't find the cause of the problem.

Comment: Does the demo app work?

Comment: Yes it works, I have also tested in debug and it gets in the DemoCameraHost.saveImage method.

Comment: But if I don't check Single-Shot Mode I don't get a preview.

Comment: With regards to your original problem, you will need to start ferreting out what is different between your app and the demo app. With regards to the preview problem, I would need to know the `Build.MANUFACTURER` and `Build.PRODUCT` of your device, so I can add it to my list of devices to eventually try to get so I can run some experiments.

Comment: any conclusions on this problem? i am having same problem with devices using 5.0.2